# How make ngIf directive globally visible in all project?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angularjs-ng-if

I have a code `<div class="flex-container" *ngIf="mail"> Some data </div>`

And i have a error `Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import `BrowserModule` in the root module and `CommonModule` in other modules where you want to use common directives.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  ...
})
class AppModule {}
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  // Now MyComponent has access to ngIf
  declarations: [MyComponent]
  ...
})
class OtherModule {}
```

`BrowserModule` exports `CommonModule`, this way it's not necessary to import `CommonModule` directly in the root module.